# jenkins in docker can not execute in host machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

i have jenkins install on docker. the jenkins have some CICD tasks that need to copy file on host machine.

here is my docker-composer:

```
  jenkins:
    image: 'bitnami/jenkins:2'
    ports:
      - '10080:8080'
      - '10443:8443'
      - '50000:50000'
    environment:
      - JENKINS_PASSWORD=admin@123
      - JENKINS_USERNAME=admin
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins-data:/bitnami/jenkins'
      - ../../:/bitnami/apps
    restart: always
```

and my task have the `cp` command like

```
cp -r $WORKSPACE/* /home/ubuntu/eshop
```

and the result allways:

```
cp: failed to access '/home/ubuntu/eshop': Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

i had checked all the permission of the folder (777 for ensuring). and change the owner to group `docker`. but nothing change.

i run docker without su, follow guide of docker official

what wrong with my installing?

Comment: Try changing the ownership to Jenkins user and then run the pipeline. See it will work or not

Comment: i have change to jenkins user too, but seem doesn't have any effected